# When did the number of the Erinyes in Greek mythology turn into just 3?

Tags: greek, myth-identification, gods

I listened to this audio lesson and other online sources, https://study.com/academy/lesson/the-furies-in-greek-mythology-symbols-names-story.html, and they mentioned older myths had an undetermined number of Furies, but the most popular myths only mention 3 by name (Alecto, Tisiphone, Megaera). Is there a collection of those older myths I can find online?